# Python Raw socket - IP_HDRINCL option

Tags: python, sockets

According to the manual page of raw sockets,

> The  IPv4 layer generates an IP header when sending a packet unless the
>          IP_HDRINCL socket option is enabled on the socket.  When it is enabled,
>          the  packet  must contain an IP header.  For receiving the IP header is
>          always included in the packet.

I'm using python to test the IP_HDRINCL socket option, so i have generated an IP Header but after enabling the option, unfortunately the sendto() method doesn't seems to be worked, i got the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "./test.py", line 35, in 
>       s.sendto(pkt, (dip , 0 ))
>       socket.error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

just keep in mind that i'm running the program with the uid 0 (root)

Note:

I don't want to use raw socket along with the PACKET FAMILY, i still want to make use of the TCP/IP stack implemented in the kernel

Here is the sample i created:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import struct
def IP():
    version = 4
    ihl = 5
    DF = 0
    Tlen = 0
    ID = 0
    Flag = 0
    Fragment = 0
    TTL = 64
    Proto = socket.IPPROTO_TCP
    ip_checksum = 0
    SIP = socket.inet_aton("172.16.122.2")
    DIP = socket.inet_aton("172.16.122.1")
    ver_ihl = (version << 4) + ihl
    f_f = (Flag << 13) + Fragment
    ip_hdr =  struct.pack("!BBHHHBBH4s4s", ver_ihl,DF,Tlen,ID,f_f,TTL,Proto,ip_checksum,SIP,DIP)
    return ip_hdr
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)

# the error occurs only when the IP_HDRINCL is enabled 

s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
dip = "172.16.122.1"
pkt = IP() + "Hello"
s.sendto(pkt, (dip , 0 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using
`s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)`instead?

You're setting the protocol to TCP but not writing the header. Perhaps when you set the IP_HDRINCL option there is some validation going on?

Comment: According to raw sockets manual page, "A  protocol  of  IPPROTO_RAW  implies enabled IP_HDRINCL", so it's the same, i just used it and it worked, thank you very much

Comment: in other words, you can tell the kernel to do not include the IP header using IPPROTO_RAW

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you probably do not have admin rights. Try launch the script with sudo (on Linux) or by administrator (on windows).